# Compiling SymbolicC++ - operator , is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to compile the SymbolicC++ library in VC++ 2010 Express (there is special VS project in the distribution), but it gives a lot of errors in *system headers*, related to `operator,`. For example:

> 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\xlocmon(410): error C2593: 'operator ,' is ambiguous

For this code in a system header:

```
if (_Str[0] < _E0 || _E0 + 9 < _Str[0])
    _Str2 += '-', ++_Off;
```

Why? How to compile it?

Comment: try and change that `,` to a `;`. bad practise to use the `,` to avoid to write a `{}` block.

Comment: @vulkanino, we all still do it from time to time though, don't we :)

Comment: @Blindy: ehm, nope.

Comment: I honestly can say I have never done it nor considered it. I would wrap a single statement in `{}` before trying to abuse the `,` that way.

Comment: Can you show us your `include` order?

Comment: And using the builtin sequence operator like that might be against reordering optimizations. +1 PlasmaHH.

Comment: RankoR, Which approach did you take to solve the problem? Reorder the header files? Or edit `<xlocmon>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, SymbolicC++ has overloaded `operator,` in such a manner that a downstream include has been affected.

You should reorder your includes such that SymbolicC++'s include comes last:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// don't want to monkey with our other headers
#include "symbolicc++.h"
```

This isn't to say the code in the `<xlocmon>` header isn't suspect, that sort of <strike>abuse</strike>usage of the comma operator is asking for trouble.

Comment: Interesting, well then SymbolicC++ abused the comma operator in a manner that caused a downstream include to barf.

Comment: Basically you need to take care to ensure `symbolicc++.h` does not get included before any of the system header files.

Comment: @RankoR: Learn to judge by content, not by badge ;)

Comment: @sixlettervariables We're you able to get the SymbolicC++ library to actually build? I'm running into the same issue, but am not sure which headers to reorder.

Comment: The file `verylong.h` includes `<iomanip>` which in turn includes `<xlocmon>`. The trouble is that `symbolicc++.h` includes `verylong.h` and later includes `symbolicc++.h` 3 more times. It seems like it would be quite tricky to reorder the headers in a way that doesn't trigger the ambiguity error.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, add parentheses:

```
    if (_Str[0] < _E0 || _E0 + 9 < _Str[0])
        (_Str2 += '-'), ++_Off;
```

Or simply write proper C++ code:

```
    if (_Str[0] < _E0 || _E0 + 9 < _Str[0])
    {
        _Str2 += '-';
        ++_Off;
    }
```

Comment: While I would like to avoid editing the system header `<xlocmon>`, this solution does indeed work and SymbolicC++ 3.35 builds successfully for me (Visual C++ 2010 Express).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another workaround which avoids having to modify `<xlocmon>`.

The dependency on `<xlocmon>` is via `verylong.h` which includes `<iomanip>` which in turn includes `<xlocmon>`. In `verylong.h`, comment out the line:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

After doing this, the build completes successfully on my system (Windows 7, Visual C++ 2010 Express).

Comment: For detailed instructions on getting SymbolicC++ to run in Visual C++ 2010 Express, see [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679416/how-do-you-install-symbolic-c-on-visual-studio-2010/13775602#13775602) answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea what their `operator,` is doing, so this may well not be valid, but that's a weird way to do things -- the following is equivalent and less weird:

```
    if (_Str[0] < _E0 || _E0 + 9 < _Str[0]) {
        _Str2 += '-';
        ++_Off;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator doesn't make any sense in 90% of the cases. The solution is to hit whoever wrote that code in the head with a blunt object, then rewrite it as:

```
if (_Str[0] < _E0 || _E0 + 9 < _Str[0])
{
  _Off++;
  _Str2 += '-';
}
```